# 2016 Chevy Malibu LS

Tags: chevrolet, noise, malibu

My Chevy Malibu is making a clicking noise underneath the car when I accelerate. Check engine light is not on.

[image]

Comment: Tell us more about your car and the symptoms. Auto? Manual.  Clicking at specific or all speeds? Does it do it in reverse? Front or back of car?  Turning corners?

Comment: Possibly an exhaust leak, a cracked or loose exhaust manifold, an issue with your CV joints, a loose wheel, or any number of other things.

Comment: Could be the fuel pump, bad ignition coil or spark plug, a relay having a conniption fit, a bad belt tensioner, or any number of things. I'd recommend recording the sound and posting the recording to YouTube, and giving a link here. If memory serves, that car came in a four cylinder and in a V6. It'd help to know which engine (trim level?) your car has.

Comment: We could also do something with a description of the clicking. For example, is it one click every now and then? Or do you feel like there are more clicks the faster the car goes? Or does it change speed / pitch for other reasons? AC / heater on or off?

Comment: When I put the car in drive and step on a glass you'll hear a weird clicking noise from underneath the car hear is off and it still does it. I just had my gas pedal replaced due to it going in reduced engine mode it was a recall on my car. But yes you can feel it when you step on the gas and brake sometimes it's like a loud click

Comment: *gass *heater. Sorry talk to text

Comment: It is an automatic and a manual. It just clicks when I put it in drive and I step on the gas to go. That's a good idea I'll record it and put it on YouTube and paste the link.

Comment: 1.5 liter. 4 cylinder

Comment: It's one click when you step on the gas